# Is there any way to use the serial port as an interruption source?

Tags: serial, interrupt, arduino-micro

I have an sketch made for reading a temp/hum sensor once every ten seconds aprox. However, I want to introduce an interruption source to send from my keyboard a magic word to make the sensor be read exactly at that instant.

By checking out the reference on [attachInterrupt()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt), I found only the ways to declare interruption pins, but nothing related to serial. What you can say about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Serial.available()` or the serialEvents can be used essentially like an interrupt.

Comment: @dandavis, not really.  Those are *polling* methods, not interrupts.  Those two methods do not "interrupt" other things that your code may be doing.  Your code must call `available` frequently or, if you are using `serialEvent`, you must make sure that `loop` doesn't block.  However, in the OP's application, polling is sufficient (see gre_gor's answer).

Comment: @slash-dev: regardless of the underpinning, to the dev, they "_can be used essentially like_"... Specifically, there's no need here for a low-level interrupt when the "main work" is only is done every 10 seconds...

Answer (score 3):

Use `millis()` for the timing of the temperature reading, then you can read from the serial in between time and won't need to use any interrupts.

```cpp
unsigned long last_measure = 0;

const byte buffer_size = 16;
char buffer[buffer_size] = "";
byte buffer_i = 0;

// setup() and other stuff

void loop() {
    if (millis() - last_measure > 10000) { // read the temperature like in the "blink without delay" example
        last_measure = millis();
        int value = readSensor();
        Serial.println(value);
    }
    while (Serial.available()) {
        char c = Serial.read();
        if (c == '\n') { // end of line, which means we got the whole string
            if (strcmp(buffer, "magic") == 0) { // compare if it matches the magic word
                int value = readSensor(); // read and print the temperature
                Serial.println(value);
            }
            buffer_i = 0; // reset the index
            buffer[buffer_i] = 0;
        }
        else if (buffer_i < buffer_size-1) { // if the buffer is not full
            buffer[buffer_i++] = c; // add char to buffer
            buffer[buffer_i] = 0; // and null terminate the string
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, guys. I considered your ideas, and then I code this solution. It works fine, right now I'm reading my sensor once every 30 minutes (1,800,000 miliseconds) and whenever I send the magic word. I hope it is useful to you:

```
void loop(){
if ((millis() - timer < 1800000) && (Serial.available() > 0)){
    magicInput = Serial.readString();
    magicInput.trim(); //Cleans input from \n at the end, otherwise never equals magicInput
    if (magicInput.equals(magicWord)){     //Elegant form for "=="
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println("  === Your request ==="); //Shows requested measurement
      Serial.println(millis() - timer); //Time since last measurement
      measure(); //
    }
  }

  if (millis() - timer >= 1800000){
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("===== Normal mode =====");  //Indicates that measurement was not requested by user
    Serial.println(millis() - timer); //Checks that 30 "exact" minutes have run
    mide();
    timer = millis();
  }
}
```

Comment: `Serial.readString()` has a timeout of 1 sec by default, so your response has an unnecessary delay. Use `Serial.readStringUntil('\n')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a logic snippet you can use:

```
unsigned long timer = 0;

void loop(){
  readSensors();
  while(millis() - timer < 10000){
    if(stringFromSerial == magicWord){
      readSensors();
    }
  }
}
```